# uninitialized constant Faker::CONFIG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

I want Faker to generate sentences in "English" language.

I have used the **require 'faker'**.

When I use **Faker::Name.name**, it works fine.

When I use **Faker::Config.locale = :en,** it gives the error `uninitialized constant Faker::CONFIG`.

Am I missing something ?
.

Comment: Are you sure that Faker::Config is camel case and not upcase?

Comment: Faker Gem Version : 0.3.1 . Yes, as per the documentation, Faker::Config is camel case. Anyways, I tried Faker:CONFIG also which gives same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using a very outdated version of the Faker gem. The current version seems to be 1.0.1.

Maybe you should just try `gem faker` first?

Comment: Thank you very much. It was indeed a problem.